# Intentionally making a C++ program run slower for test purposes?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, testing

This might be an odd question,, but is there a way to make a C++ program run slower?

I am trying to compare the performances of different operations this way:

```
DWORD start, end;

start = GetTickCount();
//...Operation 1...//
end = GetTickCount();
cout << "Exec Time (1): " << (double) end - start / (double) 1000 << "seconds";


start = GetTickCount();
//...Operation 2...//
end = GetTickCount();
cout << "Exec Time (2): " << (double) end - start / (double) 1000 << "seconds";

...
```

Output :

```
Exec Time (1) : 0 seconds
Exec Time (2) : 0.015 seconds
```

The problem is that each operation is too fast for me to compare the speeds.. 
I would like to make them run slower so that I could compare the performance when dealing with large amount of data...

Is there a way to do this?

Or actually is there a better way to test these without recording every tickcount?

Comment: You can use a 100Mhz PC from the 90'

Answer (score 2):

Often people just repeat operations thousands of times to gain their benchmarks, as running it a single time might produce an outlying result. You then always have the option to divide your result by the number of times executed.

Answer (score 1):

> *"The problem is that each operation is too fast for me to compare the speeds.. I would like to make them run slower so that I could compare the performance when dealing with large amount of data..."*

No need to *make them run slower*, just measure many calls and take the average time. You can do the following

```
DWORD start, end;

start = GetTickCount();
for(int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
    //...Operation 1...//
}
end = GetTickCount();
cout << "Average exec Time (1): " 
     << ((double) (end - start) / 10000) / (double) 1000 << "seconds" << endl;

// Analogous for Operation 2 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

GetTickCount is a low resolution timer. Try QueryPerformanceCounter with Windows or clock_gettime with Linux.